# How do i change Ubuntu installer splash screen images? Where are they located on the ISO image?

Tags: customization, custom-distributions, custom-installer

I'm using Cubic to create my own Ubuntu distro out of pure curiosity and i want to modify the installer splash screen. Swapping /usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner didn't work for me.

Comment: Vocabulary: A 'distro' is much, much more than simply swapping some files. A true 'distro' includes infrastructure for sources, distributing, bug tracking, collaboration, community, etc. Swapping files on an existing installer is fun (done it!), but it's more appropriately (and less confusingly) labelled *customization* or occasionally *remix*.

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: @David latest one i think that is 22.10

Comment: If you are not even sure of the version how are you going to customize the ISO?

Comment: My english skills' fault, i meant that the version is 22.10 and i think it's the latest one